# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_federated.python.learning' has no attribute 'algorithms'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I am trying to run the code given by Tensorflow [in their official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated), pertaining to Tensorflow-Federated.
The code is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_federated as tff

def model_fn():
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, tf.nn.softmax, input_shape=(784,),
                            kernel_initializer='zeros')
  ])

trainer = tff.learning.algorithms.build_weighted_fed_avg(
  model_fn,
  client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(0.1))
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/pythonproject2/main.py", line 43, in <module>
    trainer = tff.learning.algorithms.build_weighted_fed_avg(
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_federated.python.learning' has no attribute 'algorithms'
```

Could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, `tensorflow_federated` requires Python 3.9+. Since I was using Python 3.7, I encountered the above error.

From the [Tensorflow-Federated Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/tutorials_overview):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue described above so what you have to do:

1- upgrade your python version (3.9+) by using for example this line of code `conda install python=3.9.2` if you use virtual env in anaconda

2- upgrade your pip, setuptools, wheel `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`

3- upgrade your tensorflow-federated by using `pip install --upgrade tensorflow-federated`

I solved this problem like this.